# How to have jquery variable in .css()?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a typewriter effect that has some complicated css lines. I want the program to find the length of a php variable and set the amount of steps the cursor moves in the animation to that number, so it depends on the length of the php variable (which varies). This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myStr = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
        var length = $.trim(myStr).length + 8;
    });

    $(".anim-typewriter").css("animation", "typewriter 4s steps("+length+") 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps("+length+") infinite normal");
</script>
```

When I return the length variable, it returns the number I expect, which is correct, however, I cannot put it into the css statement.

Comment: Why is that last statement outside of the document ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

try putting the line:

```
 $(".anim-typewriter").css("animation", "typewriter 4s steps("+length+") 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps("+length+") infinite normal");
```

inside your `$(document).ready` -- the problem is that the css animation line is being evaluated becore the document is completely loaded (and therefore `length` is not defined at that time)

Answer (score 0):

Put the variables outside the $documen.ready() 
So the .css() can access it 
Because your code defined the variables after the document loaded and .css() line  execute before the document loaded the variables not exist to him in this case 
You can also put the .css() inside the document ready after the definition of the variables

Answer (score 0):

the variable 'length' is inside another function and cannot be accessed outside its scope.
try defining it globally as such

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myStr = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
    length = $.trim(myStr).length + 8;
});

$(".anim-typewriter").css("animation", "typewriter 4s steps("+length+") 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps("+length+") infinite normal");
```

variables declared without var keyword become global irrespective of where it is declared.